# clicking a button will change the image of stars from first to last

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have 4 outlined star images. Whenever I click a button, I want the first star to change its image to a filled star and whenever I click the button again I want the next star to change to a filled star and so on. I have something like this but when I click on the button, all the starts turn into filled stars. After they are all filled stars, I would like them all to turn into blank stars after the next button click.

```
starBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            im1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
            if(im1.isDirty()){
                im2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                if(im2.isDirty()){
                    im3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                    if(im3.isDirty()){
                        im4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

I have set im1 through im4 to outlined stars and R.drawable.star is a filled star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        private int mIndex = 0;  //defined as a member in your class
        .......
        starBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mIndex == 0) {
                im1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                mIndex ++;
            } else if(mIndex == 1) {
                im2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                mIndex ++;
            } else if(mIndex == 2) {
                im3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                mIndex ++;
            } else if(mIndex == 3) {
                im4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star));
                mIndex ++;
            } else {
                //do sth else
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: for the last else i added

mIndex=0;
     im1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_star));
     im2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_star));
     im3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_star));
     im4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_star));
to clear the stars. Thank you for the help!